# How can I get port number of sender service in wso2?

Tags: wso2

This is my first question, so see my effor and answer my question :) 
I need to get address of server, so I got server IP with this property

```
 <property expression="get-property('SERVER_IP')" name="StringServerIp" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

I tried this property to get the port number ,and it returns null `<property expression="get-property('system.port.no')" name="system.port.no"/>`

Please help me to get port number of sender
 any idea or any refering are appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
<script language="js">mc.setProperty("port",java.lang.System.getProperty("xxxx"));</script>
<log level="custom">
   <property name="port" expression="get-property('port')"/>
</log>
```

Here `xxxx` can be one of below.

```
mgt.transport.http.port
mgt.transport.https.port
http.nio.port
https.nio.port
```